# Динамична ли переменная, используемая в цикле PHP?

Tags: php, циклы

Будет ли изменяться знаечние `mb_strlen($str)`, используемое во второй секции цикла `for`, если его менять в самом цикле (?):

```
for ($i = $pos; $i < mb_strlen($str); $i++) {

    // ...
    if ($found == false) {
        $s1  = mb_substr($str, 0, $i);
        $s2  = mb_substr($str, $i, mb_strlen($str) - $i + 1);
        $str = $s1 . " " . $s2;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: будет... а Вам как надо ?

Comment: Чтобы менялась.

Comment: а сейчас не меняется ?

Comment: А попробовать самому никак?

Answer (score 1):

Динамична

Comment: Вы в этом точно уверены?

Comment: Она меняется => динамична. Но если вы про цикл то попробуйте выполнить следующий код: srand(); for($i=0;$i<rand ( 10 , 20 );$i++){ echo $i;} несколько раз - каждый раз у вас будет разный результат.